# Is JSON a markup language like XML?

Tags: xml, json, markup

I'm a little bit confused, because some websites tell me JSON is not a markup language like XML, but a few say the opposite. Maybe you can give me some hint?

Comment: There's http://www.jsonml.org/

Comment: The "like" xml portion of this question is removable. This is not a duplicate, just stackoverflow being overzealous.

Proof: I arrived here by googling "Is json a markup language".

Answer (score 6):

JSON is not a markup language. A dictionary definition of [markup](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/markup) is:

> a set of instructions on a manuscript or tags in an electronic document to determine styles of type, makeup of pages, and the like.

A markup language follows this theme. It is a syntax for annotating text with semantic meaning.

> For example, when I put <i>italics on this text</i>, that is done with markup.

JSON doesn't/can't do that. JSON is simply a notation for encoding common computer data types in a readable form.

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language):

> A (document) markup language is a modern system for annotating a
>   document in a way that is syntactically distinguishable from the text.
>   The idea and terminology evolved from the "marking up" of paper
>   manuscripts, i.e., the revision instructions by editors, traditionally
>   written with a blue pencil on authors' manuscripts.

So, no. JSON is not a Markup Language.

For that matter, nor is XML. [Wikipedia describes it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language#XML) as "a meta markup language" since it provides a foundation for creating markup languages on.

JSON is like XML in that it is used to structure data in a text format and is commonly used to exchange data over the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.json.org

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange language.

I guess it depends on what you understand with "Markup". :)

Comment: yeah if I look at the function of xml and json, it's nearly the same: making content readable for machines and human...

Comment: Good comment; It's all about semantics. Strictly it is not a mark up language. It's not even a language. It's just data format. But you mark up objects, arrays etc. independently for many languages. So a gray area this.